# Linear Combination of Orthogonal Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, numerical-linear-algebra

I am currently taking a Numerical Linear Algebra course where orthogonal polynomials is the current topic being discussed.

At some point regarding the aforementioned topic, the author wrote something which i cant seem to figure out why it should be true:

"Any polynomial with degree $m$ can be written as a linear combination of the first (m + 1) orthogonal polynomials $p_{0}, p_{1}, \ldots, p_{m}$"

Where orthogonal polynomials are the ones for which the following relation holds:

\begin{equation}
\left(\mathrm{p}_{\mathrm{k}} \mid \mathrm{p}_{\ell}\right)=0 \quad \mathrm{k} \neq \ell
\end{equation}

where $\mathrm{p}_{\mathrm{k}}(\mathrm{x})=\mathrm{c}_{\mathrm{k}} \mathrm{x}^{\mathrm{k}}+\mathrm{c}_{\mathrm{k}-1} \mathrm{x}^{\mathrm{k}-1}+\ldots+\mathrm{c}_{1} \mathrm{x}+\mathrm{c}_{0}$
and $\left(p_{k} \mid p_{\ell}\right)$ expresses the inner product between polynomials $p_{k}$ and $p_{\ell}$.

Can someone help me? The author did not mention any theorem or proposition for further justifications. I did find some solved examples at Burden & Faires Numerical Analysis book but i guess i am not gonna be fully satisfied until i can prove it or read a full proof.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof uses linear algebra. Orthogonality implies the polynomials in a basis are linearly independent. To see this more clearly, the inner product of a finite sum of orthogonal polynomials $\sum_{k=0}^m a_k p_k$ and a $p_i$ where $0 \leq i \leq m$ is a $c a_i$ for a constant $c$.

Comment: Interesting! Can you explain it a little bit further, please? I still cant see why it implies the result.

Comment: Specific examples are helpful. Choose a basis, say Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind. The order of $T_m(x)$ is $m$ for all $ m \geq 0$. Given a polynomial of degree 5 with constant coefficients from a field, it can be formed from a unique linear combination $\sum_{k=0}^5 a_k T_k(x)$. The coefficients $a_k$ can be found using the inner product for T, discrete or continuous. When $k>5$, $a_k=0$.  If the polynomials were not linearly independent, then one of them $T_n(x)$ would have a non-zero inner product with a $T_l(x)$ where $l \not = n$.  A general proof will be in texts on the topic.

Comment: Can you recommend a good book which contains a full proof? Burden $ Faires does not contain one.

Comment: Just found in Atkinson's numerical analysis book! Also, nice example you gave earlier.

Comment: An example text is "Linear Algebra with Mathematica" by Frank Szabo, Elsevier, 2000. Theorem 8.2 Orthogonal vectors in an inner product space are linearly independent (page 492) and Corollary 8.3 may also be of interest.  The book you mentioned may link orthogonal polynomials and vectors. The Gram-Schmidt process can be applied to polynomials to give orthonormal ones, for example applying it to the monomials gives the Legendre polynomials.